# sound manipulation engine rsound crashes in DrRacket

Tags: audio, crash, scheme, racket

For sound manipulation I am reading a tutorial about John Clements' rsound package on PLaneT. In the [rsound tutorial](http://planet.plt-scheme.org/package-source/clements/rsound.plt/1/10/planet-docs/rsound/index.html), it says to try

```
(require (planet "main.rkt" ("clements" "rsound.plt" 1 10)))
(rsound-play ding)
```

but every time I try this, DrRacket crashes. However, `(rsound-read path)` does not cause DrRacket to crash.

Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you tell me more about your platform? The most likely problem is an outdated version of PortAudio on a Linux platform, but it's hard to say for sure without knowing more.  Also, if there's any message associated with the crash, I'd really like to see it.

Comment: Winodws XP sp3 it says
AppName: drracket.exe    AppVer: 0.0.0.0         ModName: libracket3m_8aa6ug.dll
ModVer: 0.0.0.0  Offset: 0000f0df

any idea?

Comment: Ah, Windows XP.  Sadly, I don't have an XP machine to test on. I think you've resolved this project (by abandoning it :)), but the next step would be to see whether taking Racket & RSound out of the picture by just testing PortAudio works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the new version?

> (require (planet clements/rsound:2:12))

http://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/clements/rsound.plt/2/12/planet-docs/rsound/index.html